# Calling SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, distinct

I am unclear on exactly on,

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, ...
FROM table_name
```

When called on one column it gives back only distinct values of that column. What happens when we use it with multiple columns and should we ever do this?

Comment: See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

Comment: Unrelated, but: a common misconception that I see is that `distinct (col1), col2` is something different than `distinct col1, col2`. The parentheses won't change anything

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How does this work exactly?

It gives you distinct combinations of all the expression in the `SELECT` list.

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, ... 
FROM table_name ;
```

is also equivalent to:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ... 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY  col1, col2, ... ;
```

Another way to look at how it works - probably more accurate - is that it acts as the common bare `SELECT` (`ALL`) and then removes any duplicate rows. See Postgres documentation about `SELECT`: [`DISTINCT` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT).

> Should we ever do this?

Of course. If you need it, you can use it.